# Are exponentials with jointly prime bases linearly independent?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponential-function

Do the exponentials $3^x$, $4^x$ and $7^x$ have the property that for no $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \neq 0$:

$\alpha 3^x + \beta 4^x = \gamma 7^x$

What if the bases are not jointly prime, like if they were 4 and 8?

Comment: Do you mean identically so - i.e. as functions of $x$ - or that there's no (integer) $x$ for which this holds?

Comment: Function of x, sorry.

Comment: Hint: take $\gamma=1$ (you can do this without loss of generality - why?) and show that for all $\alpha, \beta$ there's some $x_0$ such that $7^x\gt \alpha3^x+\beta4^x$ for all $x\gt x_0$.

Comment: I can divide by $\gamma$ if I want to. $\alpha 3^x + \beta 4^x < (\alpha + \beta) 4^x$. Now suppose that they intersect at $x_0$. Then $7^{x_0} = c_14^{x_0}$ where $c_1= \alpha + \gamma$. Then we take the derivatives and $ln(7)7^{x_0} > ln(4)\alpha 4^{x_0}$. Thus $7^{x_0 + \epsilon} > \alpha 4^{x_0 + \epsilon}$ for sufficently small epsilon > 0. Suppose that they never intersect, then clearly equality does not hold for all X.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this was a good push in the right direction.

Comment: All exponentials with different bases are linearly independent. Say you have bases $0 < b_1 < b_2 < \dotsc < b_k$. If you have coefficients $c_1,\dotsc, c_k$ such that $c_1b_1^x + \dotsc + c_k b_k^x \equiv 0$, multiply with $f(x) =b_k^{-x}$. Then $$0 = \lim_{x\to +\infty} \biggl(c_1\biggl(\frac{b_1}{b_k}\biggr)^x + \dotsc + c_{k-1}\biggl(\frac{b_{k-1}}{b_k}\biggr)^x + c_k\biggr) = c_k.$$ Then multiply with $b_{k-1}^{-x}$ to find $c_{k-1} = 0$ and so on.

Comment: In fact, you can prove the same statement 'discreetly', without needing to take derivatives - if $7^{x_0}=c4^{x_0}$, then $7^{x_0+1}=7\cdot 7^{x_0}\gt 4\cdot 7^{x_0} = 4\cdot c4^{x_0} = c4^{x_0+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those expononential functions are linearly indipendent.

- If one of $a, b, c $ is zero we have clearly that the other two coefficients are zero.
- If two of $a, b, c$ are zero same thing.

**So we suppose** $abc \ne 0$

We can prove that $\exists x: c7^x > a3^x+b4^x$

In fact $c7^x > (a+b)4^x $ (this implies $c7^x > a3^x+b4^x$) iff $x>\frac{ln \frac{a+b}{c}}{ln(7/4)}\space \square$

---

One can generalize. Let $a_1, ..., a_n$ be real number such that $a_i>1$ and $a_1>a_2>...>a_n$ (strictly increasing!). 
We can easily show that $\exists x: \lambda_1a_1^x>\lambda_2a_2^x+...\lambda_na_n^x$ ($\lambda_i$ are arbitrary positive constants).

In fact $\exists x$ such that (why?)
 $$\lambda_1a_1^x\stackrel{(*)}{>}\left(\sum_{i=2}^{n}\lambda_i \right)a_2^x> \sum_{i=2}^{n}\lambda_ia_i^x $$
You could prove (*) which is very easy. The other inequality comes from hypothesis.

**In particular this answer to your second question.**